# Acumatica postal code validation and match

Tags: validation, acumatica, postal-code

I have created a new custom field(postal code - Usrpostalcode) in Sales Order screen and I am trying to make this field required(not working even after adding [PXDefault]
[PXUIField(..., Required = true)] ),validate it and make sure that it matches with the Postal code in the Shipping Settings.

Can anyone help me with this?

Getting this error while creating shipment on sales order screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agpCz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding PXDefault attribute should be enough to make the field required. PXDefault will prevent saving if the value is null or empty. It will raise an error and highlight the field.

**Adding the custom field in SOOrder DAC:**
[image]

**Adding the custom field to Sales Order screen:**
[image]

**Testing required field by saving without providing Postal Code value:**
[image]

**Using Inspect Element, locate the field you want to validate against:**
[image]

**In the code section, create a Graph Extension for SOOrderEntry where you will put your validations:**
[image]

**Write your validation code in that graph extension:**

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
    public const string postalCodeErrorMessage = "Sales Order postal code must match shipping address postal code.";

    // Validate just before saving, triggered when graph save function is called
    public void SOOrder_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (!ValidatePostalCode(sender, e.Row as SOOrder))
      {
         // Raise field error
         PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<SOOrderExt.usrPostalCode>(sender, e.Row, postalCodeErrorMessage);
      }
    }

    // Validation function
    public bool ValidatePostalCode(PXCache sender, SOOrder soOrder)
    {
      if (soOrder != null)
      {
        // Get SOOrder custom field Postal Code
        SOOrderExt soOrderExt = sender.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(soOrder);

        if (soOrderExt != null)
        {
          string soPostalCode = soOrderExt.UsrPostalCode;
  
          // Get current shipping address displayed on Sales Order
          SOShippingAddress shippingAddress = Base.Shipping_Address.Current as SOShippingAddress;
  
          if (shippingAddress != null)
          {
              // Special case to handle null values
              if (soPostalCode == null || shippingAddress.PostalCode == null)
              {
                  return soPostalCode == shippingAddress.PostalCode;
              }
  
              // Compare postal codes
              soPostalCode =soPostalCode.Trim().Replace(" ", "");
              string shippingPostalCode = shippingAddress.PostalCode.Trim().Replace(" ", "");
              
              return soPostalCode.Equals(shippingPostalCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
          }
        }
      }

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**When saving or when the custom postal code field lose focus, validation will be triggered:**
[image]

Comment: Using FieldVerifying as Brendan suggested is a better option if you want to validate at all time. If you want to only validate when saving, you could use only RowPersisting and drop FieldUpdated.

Comment: I made a small edit in graph extension on how to get current shipping address displayed on Sales Order because current item of cache appears to be null when I tested it. Now changed to: Base.Shipping_Address.Current as SOShippingAddress;

Comment: I am getting this error when i am trying to Copy Order after adding Postal Code Validation


Error: An error occurred during processing of the field  Postal Code : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'..

Comment: This is usually caused by a mismatch between the declared DAC type and the database type. Use a database management utility like SQL Management Studio to check the type of the custom field in the database. They should match the type of the DAC. Ex: DAC [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode=true) DB nvarchar(50)

Comment: yes...the data type in database was (int)...thank you!

Comment: Again when I try to create a shipment for sales order screen it gives me error...i have posted the screenshot in my question...please check it once

Comment: You should check and adjust the ValidatePostalCode method according to your validation business rules. That error is the validation message. In my example I made it so the custom field must match the Ship-To Info postal code. If you don't want to prevent saving on validation, you can replace SetError by SetWarning.

Comment: Even after the Postal code is same as the Shipping Address postal code this error pops up when trying to create shipment...It allows to save the order without any error.

Comment: You'll have to debug it to assess whether or not it's the same. This is more of a standard C# operation than related to Acumatica. Before the line:  soPostalCode.Equals(shippingPostalCode, [...]), output the values to acumatica trace window using PXTrace.WriteInformation("[" + soPostalCode + "]" + "[" + shippingPostalCode + "]" +(soPostalCode == shippingPostalCode).ToString());

Comment: As a test, you could have the ValidatePostalCode always return true. If that makes the error disappear then it's really just a matter of writing the proper validation code.

Comment: How can I change the data type from string to nvarchar in live system? For local system I changed it through SQL Management Studio, but the same error appears in live system " Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String"

Comment: In your DAC you want type [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]. You can specify string length with [PXString(255, IsUnicode = true)] where 255 is the string length. Equivalent DB type is nvarchar, the 'n' in nvarchar means Unicode as opposed to varchar which is not Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the value by either adding a selector or implementing FieldVerifying.

If using a PXSelector by default the selector will throw an error if not found in the backing table.

Alternatively, you can use the fields FieldVerifying event by adding it to the graph extension on sales order like the example below...

```
public class SOOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    protected virtual void SOOrder_Usrpostalcode_FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
        //search for table value...

        // if not found...

        throw new PXSetPropertyException<SOOrder.usrpostalcode>("Invalid postal code");
    }
}
```

Comment: oh okay...i'll use the FieldVerifying event then!

Thank you